# Search multiple tables.column for specific value

Tags: mysql

I've got multiple tables(8) with the same column name. Each table is a site. I want to be able to search to see which table.column has a specific value. ie. table.subnet = '10.3.30.x'. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still there? Would be good to know if our answers were helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) to get all of the values in a single query:

```
SELECT 'table1', subnet FROM table1 WHERE subnet = '10.3.30.x'
UNION
SELECT 'table2', subnet FROM table2 WHERE subnet = '10.3.30.x'
UNION
SELECT 'table3', subnet FROM table3 WHERE subnet = '10.3.30.x'
UNION
SELECT 'table4', subnet FROM table4 WHERE subnet = '10.3.30.x';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `UNION ALL` keyword. I guess what you want to do is something like this:

```
(SELECT 'table1', table1.* FROM table1 where subnet = '10.3.30.x')
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'table2', table2.* FROM table2 where subnet = '10.3.30.x')
UNION ALL
...
(SELECT 'table7', table7.* FROM table7 where subnet = '10.3.30.x')
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'table8', table8.* FROM table8 where subnet = '10.3.30.x')
```

That way, your result would have all columns where the subnet value is the specified value, along with the name of the table that row appeared in.